# Build a transmuter for a given graph and a spanning tree of it

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Give a graph and a spanning tree of it, a transmuter is an auxiliary graph derived from them and can speed up certain operations on original graph. It was invented by Tarjan:

```
Robert E. Tarjan. Applications of Path Compression on Balanced Trees. Journal of the ACM, 26(4):690–715, 1979.

Robert E. Tarjan. Sensitivity Analysis of Minimum Spanning Trees and Shortest Path Trees. Information Processing Letters, 14(1):30–33, 1982.
```

I find myself in need of a transmuter. Unfortunately I don't have access to both documents. Can someone know transmuter and / or have access to the documents elaborate a little bit about transmuter and the algorithm constructing it?

Comment: Would you like the documents or just a discussion on how to construct a graph and run a minimum spanning tree over it? Also do you want information on compressed binary search trees? B-Trees might be what you are looking for (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree).

Comment: Documents will do. But no, I'm not interested in constructing a graph and a spanning tree over it. I want to know how to construct a transmuter, which is also a graph. I edited the question to spell out my intention.

Comment: The following is a bit missleading. I don't have edit privileges. "Can someone know the data structure and / or have access to the documents elaborate a little bit about transmuter and the algorithm constructing it?". Also ACM articles are not free, and I think freely distributing them breaks copyright laws?

Comment: Edited again. Hope it is clear now. And I believe your copyright concern is true. That's probably why I couldn't find them on the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs528/handouts/applications%20of%20path%20compression.pdf from http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Applications+of+Path+Compression+on+Balanced+Trees.%22 from http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/journals/jacm/jacm26.html#Tarjan79

unfortunately http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22Sensitivity+Analysis+of+Minimum+Spanning+Trees+and+Shortest+Path+Trees.%22 has no pdf link.  see http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/db/indices/a-tree/t/Tarjan:Robert_Endre.html in case there are other papers that might help.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. That's probably the best I can get so far. I'll wait a little longer and then accept your answer if there's no one can give an explanation of the algorithm itself.